# Retrieve JSON with StackOverflow in C#

Tags: c#, json, streamreader

My problem is very simple and self-explanatory in the comments of the code.
With a url different from StackOverflow, the Json appears with no problem but, with
a Json obtained from StackOverflow it has a strange encoded form.

Here is my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //goodUrl is working in this program and in the browser.
        string goodUrl = "http://yuml.me/23db58a4.json";
        //badUrl is not working in this program, but works fine in the browser.
        string badUrl = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/me?key=qxtbTbIIEhAZFGO0QOziMA((&site=stackoverflow&order=desc&sort=reputation&access_token=mytoken&filter=!23IiyZnRyYmQ4bPZYWRA1";
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(badUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        try
        {
            string str = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            //With Bad-url, "str" ENCODE JSON but with STRANGE ASCII CODE.
            Console.Write(str);
            Console.Read();
        }
        //...
    }
```

Where is the real problem and how can I solve this?

Comment: Could you give an example of the 'strange encoded form'?

Comment: You're probably seeing a gzipped response.

Comment: One thing I will suggest is to read the response line by line and not ReadToEnd because there is a chance that the file will be pretty big.

Comment: @JohnOdom: Since he needs to parse the JOSN anyway, that won't help much.  He should actually pass the stream directly to the parser.

Comment: Well. You can see that the JSON is very small if click on that link.
The strange encode matches with the length of Json.
here what I got:
http://imgur.com/572yB6A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a compressed result.

```
var stream = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(stream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress).CopyTo(m);
try
{
    string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m.ToArray()); 
    Console.Write(str);
    Console.Read();
}
finally
{
 ........
}
```

Comment: Yeah! It worked for me!
I got a compressed result.
Many thanks!